# How to put n Lists as rows of a Data Table

Tags: c#, list, gridview, dynamic, datarow

I want to have a generic method, to achieve the following:

I have 'n' `Lists` of `string` and I want them to appear as rows of a `Data Table` under corresponding columns.

May be below code would make my question clearer:

```
List<string> list1 = new List<string>();
List<string> list2 = new List<string>();
List<string> list3 = new List<string>();
for (int num1 = 0; num1 < 4; num1++)
{
list1.Add(num1.ToString());
}
for (int num2 = 4; num2 < 8; num2++)
{
list2.Add(num2.ToString());
}
for (int num3 = 8; num3 < 12; num3++)
{
list3.Add(num3.ToString());
}
DataTable dtTable = new DataTable();
dtTable.Columns.Add("Column1", typeof(string));
dtTable.Columns.Add("Column2", typeof(string));
dtTable.Columns.Add("Column3", typeof(string));

for (int num4 = 0; num4 < list1.Count; num4++)
{
dtTable.Rows.Add(list1[num4], list2[num4], list3[num4]);
}
GridView2.DataSource = dtTable;
GridView2.DataBind();
```

In the above code, items under `list1`, `list2`, `list3` come as rows under columns `Column1`, `Column2`, `Column3` respectively like:

```
Column1 Column2 Column3
0       4        8
1       5        9
2       6        10
3       7        11
```

I have a requirement to have some 50 lists, show them under 50 different columns, ultimately binding them to a `GridView`.

I can't just keep on adding the Lists as rows manually, i.e.

```
dtTable.Rows.Add(list1[num4], list2[num4], list3[num4], list4[num4],.......,listn[num4]);
```

How to generalize the above to take in n number of lists?

Experts please help over here.

Comment: By looking at what you are doing, I have the feeling that you shouldn't extend your data as Columns.  Databases work better when the data is on the rows.  You may want to consider having two DataTables.  For example: If you want to store people's phone numbers and you don't want to limit how many phone numbers to store.  Instead of having columns names like Phone#1, Phone#2, Phone#3... etc.  You use two tables one table will have an ID# column which refers to the second table column named ID# then your data goes into the rows.  Then you can grow as much as you want row wise.

Comment: @Pabinator I don't have the advantage of using DataBases over here, I mean I can't use DB's. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Well I was referring to the DataTables as DataBases.  In other words you don't have to use a DataBase.  In my example you could have a DataTable with these columns: ID, PersonName.  Then a second DataTable with these columns: ID, PersonPhoneNumber.  Then your data on the first DataTable will be like: Row1 = 1, Pablo; Row2 = 2, Jose; etc. and for the second DataTable your data will look like: Row1 = 1, (555) 123-4567; Row2 = 1, (555) 123-1234.  In these case you know that the phone numbers (555) 123-4567 and (555) 123-1234 are Pablo's phone numbers. And you can grow as long as you want.

Comment: What are the requirements for the column names? Can they just be numberd all the way to 50 as you have in yor example? Does the table need to have multiple rows?

Comment: @MikeHixson Nice catch..Well i think I can manage the Column Names as Column1, Column2.... Column50. If there had to be different column names, how could one approach this? Any Idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this. Create a method to handle all the lists

```
private void PopulateGrid(params List<string>[] list)
{
    DataTable dtTable = new DataTable();
    for (int listIndex = 0; listIndex < list.Length; listIndex++)
    {
        dtTable.Columns.Add(string.Format("Column{0}", listIndex), typeof(string));
    }

    for (int rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < list[0].Count; rowIndex++)
    {
        DataRow dr = dtTable.NewRow();
        for (int listIndex = 0; listIndex < list.Length; listIndex++)
        {
            dr[listIndex] = list[listIndex][rowIndex];
        }
        dtTable.Rows.Add(dr);
    }
    dataGridView1.DataSource = dtTable;
}
```

Then create a main `List` so you can add as many lists you desire

```
List<List<string>> allLists = new List<List<string>>();

/* Code to populate the lists */    

allLists.Add(list1);
allLists.Add(list2);
allLists.Add(list3);
...
allLists.Add(listn);
```

Then call method

```
PopulateGrid(allLists.ToArray());
```

Comment: your approach looks neat.Let me try

Comment: It worked mate. Thanks for that. If I need different column names then, what kind of procedure should I follow.

Comment: Well... you can try to change the main `List` for a `Dictionary<string, List<string>>` and take the `key` as the name of the column.